# Compiz changes my window's theme

Tags: compiz, xubuntu, ambiance

I have Gnome Shell, Unity and Xubuntu on my computer and I would like to use compiz in Xubuntu. Whenever I put in "compiz --replace" it changes my window's theme from Greybird to Gnome's Ambiance. It doesn't seem like I can change it back in Xubuntu's settings menu, when I click on Window Manager, everything is blank. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

When you use "compiz --replace", you are replacing xfwm4 with compiz. That means the xfwm4 window manager is no longer running. Since greybird is part of xfwm4, it won't run either.

Answer (score 0):

You can try just logging out and back in as another shell (Click the gear) to get back into the settings. As well I got the Compwiz manager when I was messing around with it.

sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager

Comment: If this doesn't work you may have to edot the ~/.config/xbuntu-session file to include the compiz profile